# ARC enabled for Qt project on MacOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, compilation, automatic-ref-counting

I am developing a Qt application for macos.

That application uses some objective-c++ files. I would like to know if ARC is enabled in the build.

In flag `QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS` I am neither adding fobjc-arc flag nor fno-objc-arc.

Does it mean I am not using ARC or it is enabled by default?

I am using MacOS 10.14 Mojave

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARC is disabled by default. You have to enable it via the command line switch.

Comment: Reference: https://wiki.qt.io/Apple_Platforms_Coding_Conventions